# Manually refresh project files on local server? (Netbeans)

Tags: php, netbeans, project, refresh

I have a Netbeans PHP project set to run on a local server. I added some files in the filesystem; Netbeans detects and shows the changes in it's project view, but does not propagate the changes to the local server (based in a different folder). Hence project files on the local server are missing or out of date.

Can Netbeans manually refresh the project files on local server?

Comment: It can but I'm running into a but at the moment where it isn't propagating changes made to a file.

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use Menu->Source->Scan For External Changes (if I understand you correctly)

Answer (score 5):

Source->Scan For External Changes

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to disable ‘Enable auto-scanning of sources’ checkbox under: Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files. After you do this, the ‘Refresh Folder’ option will appear.

Comment: I am using netbeans 12.2 (PHP) and the copy service is still running message every time I ran the app from the IDE.  Drove me nuts.  Thanks.