# Netbeans doesn't update php files on local server

Tags: php, netbeans-7

I'm having the same issue as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162154/manually-refresh-project-files-on-local-server-netbeans). I'm working on mac osx using netbeans 7.0. I will however add more in that when I click "run" I get a message that "copy support is still running" so I think maybe the issue is with this process. I have googled but there's nothing really concrete on the subject or issue.
I have also tried fumbling around netbeans to see if I can disable this process but found nothing so far.

Comment: I have the same problem. Files don't get uploaded when I save a file. I can manually upload the file however by rightclicking the file and click Upload. When I do this, I get the same message: "copy support is still running".

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The only workaround I've found was restarting netbeans, but the problem reappears after a period of time.

Comment: @AllisonChristiansen I upgraded to 7.0.1 and the issues went away. However the IDE hangs after 3-4 hours of running nb another issue I just resolved

Comment: I have 7.1 and it still does it for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to 7.2 before this bug finally disappeared

Answer (score 2):

I've found that restarting Net Beans will get rid of this bug.

Also if you're connecting the the same FTP server at the same time in a different program, you're gonna have a bad day.